# React native log-in troubles with SecureStore saving a jwt

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, expo

I am running into some problems with saving my jwt upon log-in
as you can see i call two different functions to get and save my jwt and one more for debug purposes

What i dont get is why when i press a single time on my connection button it doesn't save the jwt but it does upon my second press of the button ?

Do you happen to know how i can fix that ?
here is my LoginScreen code :

```
import { Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';



const LoginScreen = () => {

  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  async function getToken(){
    try {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
        if (user) {
          const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult();
          setToken(idTokenResult.token);
          console.log('token set')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    async function saveToken(jwt, token) {
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(jwt, token);
    }

    async function getValueFor(key) {
      let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
      if (result) {
        console.log(" Here's your value in LoginScreen  \n" + result);
      } else {
        console.log('No values stored under that key.');
      }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      if (user){
        console.log('here')
      }
    }) 


    // unsubscribe va stopper le listner firebase lorsque l'utilisateur sort de la page login
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const handleLogin = async () => { 


    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(userCredentials => {
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      getToken()
      console.log('firebase : logged in')
    })
    .catch(error => setError(error.message))
    saveToken('jwt', token);
    getValueFor('jwt');

  }



  
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding">

      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        {error ? <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</Text> : null}
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Identifiant'
          value={email}
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder='Mot de passe'
          value={password}
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.textView}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.text} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}>
          <Text>Mot de passe oublié ?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.text} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}>
          <Text>Pas encore de compte ? Inscris-toi ici.</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View
        style={styles.buttonContainer}>

        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleLogin}
        style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Connexion</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>



      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

and a screenshot of my terminal when I press a single time my button :

[image: terminal screenshot]

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the functions are `async`, then you need to await for the token to be saved in the store. Therefore change your method to the following:

```
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(async userCredentials => {
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      await getToken()
      console.log('firebase : logged in')
    })
    .catch(error => setError(error.message))
    await saveToken('jwt', token);
    await getValueFor('jwt');

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did not pay attention to the async functions however even with your changes my method stays the same (behaving the same way as before i mean)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own post in the event that someone happens to have the same trouble,in the end it is bad habit to call an async methond after a ".then", to fix that i needed to store the result of my call within a const

```
  async function getToken(){
try {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult();
      return idTokenResult?.token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


  const handleLogin = async () => { 
try {
await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

 const userToken = await getToken();
 await SecureStore.setItemAsync('jwt', JSON.stringify(userToken));
 setToken(userToken);
} catch (err) {
 console.log(err.message)
}

getValueFor('jwt')}
```

The previous code are the changes made on my "LoginScreen" file, by storing my getToken result in the "userToken" const my problem went away

I am still open to any more in-depth explanation that anyone could have, thx